# Can't create URL laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am following a tutorial to learn Laravel 8. I've created a simple view that contains 3 articles. Each article has a link to another html page. The exercise is to create URLs in `web.php`.ur
I have 2 views post.blade.php and posts.blade.php(the main one) , the other articles in html are contained in a posts folder in ressources.

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($view) {
    $post = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../ressources/posts/{$view}.html");

    return view('post', [
        'post' => $post,
    ]);
});
```

This is the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/my-first-post`

This the error I get:

> file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel2\laravel2\routes/../ressources/posts/my-first-post.html): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I don't understand what went wrong since I'm copying exactly what the tutorial is doing.

Comment: The tutorial is not suitable to learn Laravel. Choose a good one

Comment: `ressources` should most likely be `resources`. But why are you using `file_get_contents` instead of returning a [view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) which automatically pulls from the resources folder?

Comment: i guess i'm just gonna see another tutorial and start over thanks guys

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch

Answer (score 1):

Start from here https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch

You will have each nuts and bolts of laravel clear. This series is very precise to get you started in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

In routes/web.php page

```
Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
```

And in View page

```
 <a  href="{{url('/posts')}}">Posts</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i want to say that if your instructor really told you to write this
`file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../ressources/posts/{$view}.html")`     , then he doesn't know anything about laravel and the MVC structure. stop following that.

This is the solution based on what i understood from your example:

1. so there is a html file named 'my-first-post.html' in your 'ressources/posts' directory. Rename it to 'my-first-post.blade.php'
2. in the post.blade.php file, just include that file using     `@include('posts.' . $post)`
   and change the controller to this:

```
    Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($post) {
        return view('post', [
            'post' => $post,
        ]);
    });
```